# Escape IO Monad during prototyping

Tags: haskell, ghci

How can I make my GHCI prototyping more robust? I am locked inside IO monad just because I read my data from a file. It is a bit frustrating having to stitch `liftM` every time.

```
λ: let q xml = fmap (filterChildrenName f) $ elChildren xml
λ: liftM q xml
[[Element {elName = QName {qName = "link", qURI = Nothing, qPrefix = Nothing}, elAttribs = [], elContent = [Text (CData {cdVerbatim = CDataText, cdData = "http://planet.haskell.org/", cdLine = Nothing})], elLine = Nothing}]]
λ
```

Comment: You can effectively think of every command you run in GHCi as being in an IO monad, shouldn't need to lift.

Comment: You could also use `Control.Applicative`. It introduces an alias for fmap (`<$>`) which makes things look a bit nicer, and it also introduces `<*>` which you could use instead of fmap (again, making things look nicer).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since gchi is in IO, you can use `<-` instead of let to bind variables

```
xml <- loadFromFile
q xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The main disadvantage of `let` and `<-` is that you lose all bindings after reloading. To use permanent bindings in the source file, you can also use `unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a` from `System.IO.Unsafe`. It's highly indesirable in the production code (only when you are really know what you do — some low-level optimization and hackery, for example), but quite acceptable during the prototyping.